# Probability of rain on weekend

Tags: probability

The probability of raining on Saturday is $30\%$
The probability of raining on Sunday is $40\%$

a) What is the probability of raining on weekend?

I got $58$%, is this right?

I did $P(\text{rain+rain})$ + $P(\text{rain}+\text{no rain})$ combinations etc

and added all the combinations with a rain on one of the days to get $0.58$

b) What is the assumption made?

That raining on Saturday and raining on Sunday are independent events.

c) If events are not independent, what is the maximum and minimum probability of rain on the weekend?

I don't know how to approach c), could you please help?

Kind regards

Alex

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

We set $A$ = Rain on Sat, $B$ = Rain on Sun, then

$$ P(A\cup B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$$

You should have something like the above formula in your lecture notes. What can you say about $P(A\cap B)$ if A, B are independent? (you can use this to solve a), although there's nothing wrong with your approach). This term is the only one where independence plays a role: for c), consider how small the term can get (hint: in this case, it can be 0) and how, and how large it can get (hint: in this case, it can be 0.3) and how.

Comment: I have no lecture notes Im just learning via google.  If A,B independent does that make ANB = 1? I still can't understand the reasoning behind c) sorry :(

Comment: Well, what definition of independence do you use? Usually, two events A, B are said to be independent if and only if P(ANB) = P(A) * P(B).